# How to find if the consumer is using TLS port or PLAINTEXT port?

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to find if Kafka consumers are using TLS listener or PLAINTEXT listener. I would like to disable the PLAINTEXT listener. But before making the changes, would like to know if any consumer is using PLAINTEXT listener?

Answer (score 1):

If the connection is using TLS, you're required to set SSL client properties, so that'll be immediately obvious if look at the source code or logs from those clients...

Otherwise, without using Wireshark to inspect the network traffic, you'll need direct access to the broker or Zookeeper and look at what are the protocols used by `advertised.listeners` in the broker settings, however this will not tell you if clients are actually using it; for that `netstat` and looking at open connections from the brokers might be the only reasonable option.

For instance, iterating over `kafka-consumer-groups` output will show connected consumers, but not protocols (or producers).

If you disable one listener, producers will need changed as well; you can't only have listeners for consumption.